# pythonanywhere django python error while deploying

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

#### Error log

```
2016-06-03 19:07:43,699 :Error running WSGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 154, in __call__
app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 170, in import_error_application
raise e
ImportError: No module named wsgi
```

#### WSGI File

```
import os
import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = "/home/pratkm/mysite"
if project_home not in sys.path:
sys.path.append(project_home)



# set environment variable to tell django where your settings.py is
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "mysite.settings"


# serve django via WSGI in Django < 1.7
#import django.core.handlers.wsgi
#application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
# serve django via WSGI in Django >= 1.7
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I have tried using virtualenvs but nothing helps i am using python 2.7 and django 1.9 please help me solving this error my settings.py file is in mysite folder and so i have configured in wsgi file

Comment: No module named wsgi means that you're either not running the command to run the server while in the proper directory, or your command isn't correctly specifying where the wsgi file is located. 

I can't be sure though without knowing a few things:

1) What's the command you're running to start the worker? 
2) What's the working directory in which you're running that command?

Comment: Check out our [detailed debugging guide for import errors](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError) on the PythonAnywhere help pages...